# Is hot reloading enabled in blazor webassembly project for VS-2022 and DotNet6?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have installed vs 2022 and dotnet 6 in my environment.

I am so much excited to find that hot relaoding is working in debug mode of blazor server project. But I found that hot reloading is not working in debug mode of blazor webassembly project.

Instead, it is working when I run the application in watch mode by adding the following code in lunchsettings

```
"HotReloadDotNet6": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "hotReloadProfile": "blazorwasm"
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does hot reloading of webassembly project  work in the way it works in the blazor server project ?